# Response json data

Tags: java, jquery, json, rest

My content header showing response as string even though i have returned Json data from my rest service. This problem particularly happening in post request in ajax function call?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">/script> 
function authenticate(Source,Destination) {
   $.ajax
    ({
      type: 'POST',
        url: 'REST/WebService/InsertFeeds',
        dataType:'json',
        //async: false,
        data:{'Source': Source, 'Destination': Destination },
        //headers: { 
        contentType: 'application/json', 
        //},
        error:function()
        {
            alert("unsuccessfull");
        },
        success:function(feeds)
        {   
            alert(feeds);
        }
     });
  }
```

My Rest Service code for data inserting using post annotation:

```
@Path("/WebService")

public class LoginService 
{

    @POST
    @Path("/InsertFeeds")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces("application/json")
        public String messageFeed2(@FormParam("Source") String Source,@FormParam("Destination") String Destination)
    {
        String feeds  = null;
        try 
        {

            String feedData=null;
            ProjectManager projectManager= new ProjectManager();
            feedData=projectManager.InsertFeeds(Source,Destination);
            feeds=FeedTransformer.UserFeeding(feedData);//converts string in Json format using gson library

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
        return feeds;
    }


}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing ?

Comment: Json is a string, so of course it is retrieved as such, its not an object till you convert it to one

Comment: Firebug showing data returned in response part not in json content means json object is not getting returned why?

Comment: malformed json response? http://jsonlint.com/ to check if its malformed or not.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an issue but you're not sending json in your request but rather in x-application/www-urlencoded

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
success:function(feeds)
    {   
        alert(feeds);
    }
```

To

```
success:function(feeds)
    {   
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(feeds);
        console.log(obj);
    }
```

**Note:** now you can use var obj because when you get the response from Rest service it is a json string so you have to convert it into object.

Comment: jquery automatically converts a valid json string to an object when the dataType is set to json, which he has